# Copying Cell Value to template sheet in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-2016

Currently I am using a main Excel Workbook where membership information is entered into set Ranges, e.g. "Member" refers to a cell where a Member Number is added.

The entered information then needs to be transferred/copied to an Invoice template, indicated by

```
"folderPath & "\Templates\invoice.xlsx"",
```

the trouble arises when the codes reaches

```
"Cells.Range("B11").Value = Range("Member").Value"
```

Note: "Member" is on Main Worksheet and "B11" is on Template sheet.

Previously a Userform was used to enter the data and transferred to the template from there. The code below worked in that scenario.
However since transferring/adapting it slightly to function in an Excel worksheet, it fails on the line.

There are approximately 10+ cells that need to be copied, so a efficient method is preferred.
I have researched this and haven't found a 'perfect' answer as of yet.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "\Templates\invoice.xlsx")
'copy data to the template
Cells.Range("B11").Value = Range("Member").Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mention from which workbook you need to copy and where you to paste like

```css
Dim wb As Workbook, wbk As Workbook, wbk1 As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "\Templates\invoice.xlsx")

Set wbk = Workbooks("invoice.xlsx")
'repalce your soruce workbook name with correct extension xlsm
Set wbk1 = Workbooks("sorce.xlsx")
'please change the sheet index with name as you wish
wbk.Sheets(1).Cells.Range("B11").Value = wbk1.Sheets(1).Cells.Range("Member").Value
```

Hope this is what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Below Code for Copying cell

```
Dim xlwb As Workbook    
Set xlws = xlwb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
xlws.Cells(1, 3) = (xlws.Cells(1, 1))
```

Comment: Would you mind providing an example given the original code?